# Display first name of logged in user?

Tags: functions, shortcode, username

I'm trying to create shortcodes that will display both avatar and logged in user first name in a text widget. I have managed to create something that displays the avatar, but not the username.

My code is as follows:

```
    <?php
// show user avatar if logged in
function colaborator_avatar($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
        return get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ));
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_avatar', 'colaborator_avatar');

// show user avatar if logged in
/**/
function colaborator_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
    return get_user_meta( $new_user->ID, 'first_name', true );

    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');

?>
```

Have in mind that this is not for an specific ID, this to show on screen which user is logged in.

By the way, is it possible to define the avatar's size?

EDITED: Corrected a typo error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that both the functions have the same name - colaborator_avatar().

Make sure that $new_user contains the current user. Else use get_current_user_id() like this:

```
get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true );
```

Show avatar and first name:

```
// show user avatar if logged in
function colaborator_avatar($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
        return get_avatar(get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ));
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_avatar', 'colaborator_avatar');

// show username if logged in
function colaborator_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
    return get_user_meta( $new_user->ID, 'first_name', true );

    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');
```

Or show Username:

```
function colaborator_nome($atts) {     
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {    
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo $current_user->user_login;
    } 
} 

add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');
```

Comment: I tried it like this:
`function colaborator_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
   get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true );
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');
`
It didn't work.

Comment: You need to add echo. Like this:

function colaborator_nome($atts) {     
 if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {    
  echo get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'first_name', true );     
 } 
} 

add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');

Comment: Not working. =(

Comment: It's returning a blank space.

Comment: Have you set your first name in your profile? The code is tested and it does work.

Comment: Ah, that was it. I believe this will be a problem then. Changed `first_name` to `user_login` and it didn't work.

Comment: Thats becuase user_login is not a user meta. Use this to displat current username: function colaborator_nome($atts) {     
 if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {    
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  echo $current_user->user_login;
 } 
} 

add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');

Comment: Alright. Do you mind editing your question by showing both solutions?

Comment: The answer is updated!

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. I believe this will help other people too, since most things in Wordpress are plugin related.

Comment: Can you answer me just one more question? What if the user has no name, how can I display a fake name instead, like "Nameless Person"?

Comment: Sorry I must have missed this. That would be something like this (Not tested and maybe not that pretty) :

// show username if logged in
function colaborator_nome($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
    $firstname = get_user_meta( $new_user->ID, 'first_name', true );
    if($firstname == '' ) {
        $display = 'Nameless Person';
    } else {
        $display = $firstname;
    }
    return $display;

    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');

Answer (score 0):

I searched for 'wordpress get name of logged in user' and the first result gave [wp_get_current_user](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/), which will show logged in user first name. Examples of how to use from that page:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 
/*
 * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 * if ( ! ( $current_user instanceof WP_User ) ) {
 *     return;
 * }
 */
printf( __( 'Username: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_login ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User email: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_email ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User first name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_firstname ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User last name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->user_lastname ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User display name: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->display_name ) ) . '<br />';
printf( __( 'User ID: %s', 'textdomain' ), esc_html( $current_user->ID ) );
```

Comment: What does textdomain stand for?

Comment: it's a parameter on the __() Wordpress translation function .. I quickly pasted the example code but the main part you need is e.g. `$current_user->user_firstname`

Comment: Should it be like this?

`function colaborator_avatar($atts)
{
    if (is_user_logged_in() && !is_feed()) {
 return    $current_user->user_firstname
    }
}
add_shortcode('colaborator_nome', 'colaborator_nome');`

Comment: did you try it? does it work?

Comment: Just tried it, site crashed (error).

Comment: you're missing the line that sets the $current_user variable

Comment: Thx for the help so far. You've been of great help since the other questions.